# Replace Authentication object after successful authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring application that uses OAuth2. After a successful login, I can see a
`OAuth2AuthenticationToken` in the users security context.

I'd like to replace this token by a different implementation of `Authentication`like PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.

How can I do this?
So far I tried to replace the `Authentication` in the `SecurityContext` from an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. But I'm still seeing an `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` after this code ran.

```
@Component
public class SecurityHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {
      
       PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken newToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("test-user","pw");
       token.setAuthenticated(true);

       SecurityContext secContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
       secContext.setAuthentication(token);

       HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
       session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", secContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an easy task on OAuth2 resource servers, but not on OAuth2 clients. Can you provide more details about your use case (why do you need to opt-out `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the securityHandler to the successHandler of oauth2Login?

```
 @Bean
 public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http,SecurityHandler securityHandler) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2Login(c -> c.successHandler(securityHandler))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .build();
    }
```